# Naming an image link as a variable for reuse in Laravel/HTML/CSS

Tags: php, html, css, image, laravel

I have an image stored in public/images/image.jpg

I am using this image in several files. However, for the sake of convenience and saving time I would like to store that reference link as a variable. So instead of using `<img src="/images/image.jpg">` it would be `<img src="variable_name">`. This would also allow me to edit the path that the variable is set to, without having to do it each time I use the image.

Thanks,

Comment: do you have PHP skills? this can be accomplished from several ways on the server-side... have you tried anyone? Maybe a constant? DB?

Comment: which version of laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file in the `app/config` directory. Let's call it `constants.php`. In there you have to return an array of config values.

```
return [
    'images' => [
        'myfixedImg1' => 'www.domain.es/public/images/img/img1.jpg',
        'myfixedImg2' => 'www.domain.es/public/images/img/img2.jpg'
    ]
];
```

And you can access all of them like this: `Config::get('constants.images');`

or a concrete one like: `Config::get('constants.langs.en');`